# call data using CoreData

Tags: ios, entity-framework, core-data, swift3, tableview

I wanna retrieve data using CoreData but except the first data others become fault with no reason. I tried to redo it from scratch but I face the problem.

The weirdest thing is I tried the same method on other entity it shows data on tableViewController except from this entity.

I could print all the data from the URL but when come to storing step is perfect without an error but the data fail without any error message

(entity: Promo; id: 0xd000000000400002  ; data: )
 (entity: Promo; id: 0xd000000000440002  ; data: )
 (entity: Promo; id: 0xd000000000480002  ; data: )

```
//this is how i store data from URL
                        let promosCO = jUser["created_on"] as? String ?? ""
                        let promosdesc = jUser["descr"] as? String ?? ""
                        let promosImg = jUser["img"] as? String ?? ""
                        let promosIsDel = jUser["is_deleted"] as! Int
                        let promosIsDelStr = String(promosIsDel)
                        let promosTitle = jUser["title"] as? String ?? ""

                        let promotion = Promo(context: context)

                        //save it with userdefaults
                        promotion.promoID = Int16(jsonIndex)
                        jsonIndex = jsonIndex + 1

                        promotion.promoCreateOn = promosCO
                        promotion.promoDesc = promosdesc
                        promotion.promoImg = promosImg
                        promotion.promoIsDeleted = promosIsDelStr
                        promotion.promoTitle = promosTitle

                        appDelegate.saveContext()
```

Comment: an object being faulted or unfaulted is generally not an issue.  The data will be there when you need it.  If you are logging and seeing faults that is not a reason for concern. Generally if it appears that there are no values set in the object, my first guess is that there are no values set in the object.

Comment: if that the case izzit possible for you to teach me on how to check whether it successfully save the data or not?

Comment: i am not clear what the problem is

Comment: I can't tell what problem you're having either. Your question is not very clear.

Comment: songsong [<Promo: 0x600000491580> (entity: Promo; id: 0xd000000002b40002 <x-coredata://EFCE3A50-A3B8-44BB-9F20-37FD6A8C4C49/Promo/p173> ; data: {
    promoCreateOn = "2017-09-17";
    promoDesc = "All products ";
    promoID = 1;
    promoImg = "promotion-management.jpg";
    promoIsDeleted = 0;
    promoTitle = "50% Discount";
}),
<Promo: 0x6000004915d0> (entity: Promo; id: 0xd000000002b80002 <x-coredata://EFCE3A50-A3B8-44BB-9F20-37FD6A8C4C49/Promo/p174> ; data: <fault>)]

Comment: the question is i not sure why i only get the first data but the 2nd data onwards all the data are unretrievable becomes <faults>

Comment: Try logging the actual values in the object you want - not the object itself.